# Should we do nil check for non-optional variables?

Tags: swift, null

I have a function (`abc`) as follows and I should throw an error when the arguments passed are empty or nil, should I check for `nil` too or only empty is enough?

```
public func abc(forURL serviceUrl:String,serviceID:String, error:inout Error? )throws ->[AnyHashable : Any]{
        guard serviceUrl != nil, !serviceUrl.isEmpty else {
            let argError:Error = MapError.emptyArgumentUrl.error()
            error = argError
            throw argError
        }
        guard !serviceID.isEmpty else {
            let argError:Error = MapError.emptyArgumentServiceId.error()
            error = argError
            throw argError
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serviceID` is **not an optional**.

That means **it can't be nil**.

So no, there is no need for that check.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but run time It could be nil rt??

Comment: @RaviKiran No, it can't be.